# Changing user role name Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been changing user roles name on wordpress how ever
If i call

```
implode(', ', $user->roles)
```

I still get the original role names, Administrator, Subscriber, etc.

So, i figured something like this would be the correct way.

```js
            if(implode(', ', $user->roles) = "administrator"){
       $role = "Site owner";
      }
      else{
       $role = "User";
      }

                       echo $role;
```

I am running this for each user,how ever this does not work.
What should i be doing to change the names? the backend presents the name correctly. how ever i wish to have the names on the front end for the users accounts.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. But if you want to change user role name, you can use like this. https://www.isitwp.com/change-default-role-names-administrator-editor-author-contributor-subscriber/

Comment: this only changes the user role in the backend,

Im using `implode(', ', $user->roles)` to display the user role underneath the users profile on my site.

How ever. it still says subscriber or admin or what ever role it originally was.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, a user's role can be set by creating an instance of the `WP_user` class, and calling the `add_role()` or `remove_role()` methods.

**Example**

Change a subscribers role to editor

```
// NOTE: Of course change 3 to the appropriate user ID
   $u = new WP_User( 3 );

// Remove role
   $u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

// Add role
   $u->add_role( 'editor' );
```

Hopefully that's more helpful than my initial response, which wasn't necessarily as helpful.